# Можно ли узнавать текущее ограничение скорости на маршруте или (еще лучше) без маршрута

Tags: yandex-maps-api

товарищи, коллеги!

Не подскажете, есть ли возможность считывать текущее ограничение скорости на участке дороги? 
(я про знак скорости в правом верхнем углу экрана, который краснеет при превышении) .

У меня вопрос сугубо практический, хочу, чтобы при превышении скорости издавался постоянный звуковой сигнал, и этот сигнал прекращался только после выхода из зоны превышения, а то пикнет один раз - и сиди смотри на экран пока не станет знак белым, отвлекает от дороги. Хочется, чтобы как "счетчик гейгера" скрипел пока скорость не сбавишь.

Это касается как режима ведения по маршруту, так и просто открытого приложения. Думаю эта функция была бы очень востребована рядовыми водителями.

Сам я не большой специалист в программировании, в голову пришла только идея делать скриншот экрана раз через малые промежутки времени и анализ: стала ли определенная точка красной или нет.

Всем откликнувшимся заранее спасибо!

/Алексей Рысаев

Comment: Может лучше задать этот вопрос службе поддержки Яндекс навигатора?

Comment: Человечество придумало дорожные знаки, почему бы не следить за ними (к тому же это *обязанность* водителя)? Навигатор вообще-то вторичен и может врать в любую сторону.